# uploaded files and images not showing

Tags: media, files

When i upload a file, be it a avatar picture or image, the file loads however does not display.

I have checked the permissions on my hosting environment and it seems that everye uploaded file gets a 664 permission and apache as owner.

How can i give the uploaded files the proper permission automatically?

Answer (score 1):

To fix the files permission, your folders and files needs to be readable and writable by Apache user.

Example commands to fix your permissions
(assuming `www-data` is your Apache user, prefix with `sudo` if required):

```
chgrp -vR www-data "$(drush dd %files)" "$(drush dd %private)"
chmod -vR ug+rwX "$(drush dd %files)" "$(drush dd %private)"
```

You need to have `drush` command available. If you don't have `drush`, just replace above sub-commands in double-quotes with proper locations to your `%files` and `%private` folders.

Then as Drupal admin go to *Reports -> Status Report* and check for file-system related warnings.

Answer (score 0):

664 should be sufficient to view the image.

However Drupal's image module creates different versions of uploaded images.

It needs to be able to write them into the files directory and create new directories, so your files directory (or at least the 'styles' directory within it) wants 755 permissions recursively (`chmod -R 755 sites/default/files/styles`)

Comment: After each attempt to upload an image i get two errors in my recent logs:
1.The file permissions could not be set on public://styles/thumbnail/public/pictures.
2.Failed to create style directory: public://styles/thumbnail/public/pictures

However the /pictures folder has a 775 permission..

Comment: including the subfolders

Comment: I am running into the very same issue on drupal 8.x @Byron. Did you finally solve your problem ?